# Cross-fading divs with jQuery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can do it, but wondering if there is a more straightforward way. I have two divs, one of which is initially hidden. While hidden, a div should not be taking any screen space at all, so I'm using `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none`. However, jQuery's `fadeIn()` only handles the latter, so the code is

```
<style>
    .hidden { visibility: hidden; }
    .nodisplay { display: none; }
</style>
```

and in js/jquery:

```
$("#hideThis").fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $("#hideThis").addClass('hidden'); // add visibility: hidden after fadeOut
    $("#showThis").addClass('nodisplay'); // add display: none before fadeIn
    $("#showThis").removeClass('hidden'); // remove visibility: hidden
    $("#showThis").fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $("#showThis").removeClass('nodisplay'); // remove display: none
    });
});
```

Works just fine, but with all this juggling of css classes, am I missing something simpler?

Comment: Give us your initial HTML, too.

Comment: "While hidden, a div should not be taking any screen space at all, so I'm using visibility: hidden rather than display: none" is contradictory. `visibility: hidden;` maintains the layout of the element on the page, so it still takes up space. So does `opacity`. And in jquery, you can use `$.fadeTo()` to mimic the `$.fadeIn()/$.fadeOut()` but with `opacity` instead of `display: none/block`

Comment: without seeing your html, seems like this does the same thing as your existing code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peZNgV